# Sum over polarization in scalar QED

Tags: quantum-field-theory

In scalar QED,  photon can interact with the scalar particle through $e^2 A_\mu A^\mu\phi^\dagger \phi+i e A^\mu(\phi^\dagger \partial_\mu\phi-\partial_\mu\phi^\dagger \phi)$. In the process 
\begin{equation}
\phi^*(k_1) \phi(k_2) \to \gamma(p_1) \gamma(p_2)
\end{equation} there are $t$, $u$-channel diagrams as well as the four-point interaction. But it's claimed that the $t$, $u$-channel contributions vanish in the non-relativistic limit when the relative velocity between the two incoming particles is very small, which can be accomplished in the $\phi^* \phi$ bound state, such as the bound state of stop quarks $\tilde{t}$. The amplitude is:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{M} \propto \frac{4 k_1\cdot \epsilon_1\, k_2\cdot \epsilon_2}{t-m_{\tilde{t}}^2}+\frac{4 k_1\cdot \epsilon_2\, k_2\cdot \epsilon_1}{u-m_{\tilde{t}}^2}-2\epsilon_1\cdot\epsilon_2
\end{equation}
I can take the square in two ways which give me different result:

(1) In the non-relativistic limit, $\vec{k}_1=\vec{k}_2=0$. Then we can write $k_1=(E,0)$, $k_2=(E,0)$, $\epsilon_1=(0,\vec{\epsilon}_1)$, $\epsilon_2=(0,\vec{\epsilon}_2)$, it's manifest that the first two terms in the amplitude vanish, as expected.

But
(2) when I try to use the replacement $\epsilon_1^\mu \epsilon_1^{*\nu}\to g^{\mu\nu}$, the contributions from $t$ and $u$ channels are not zero. So the problem lies in the replacement.

So my question is, when can we trust this replacment?